# Does an island need five colors, if there is a unique color assigned to the sea?

Tags: coloring

Suppose you specify that the sea must be a royal blue, and no land territory is allowed to be. Does the map then need five colors? Or can the island necessarily be colored with three (non-royal blue) colors?

Comment: One can make a map of an island consisting of a circular disc surrounded by an annulus, where the annulus consits of three countries each touching the other two. If the sea color is not allowed for an island country this map requires 5 colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need five colors.

Suppose an odd number, three or more, of regions border the sea and inside this ring is just one additional region. To color this ring you need three colors. You are then not allowed to use any of those colors for the inner region, and by the problem statement you cannot color this region with the sea color. By the pigeonhole principle you then need a fifth color.

(Unless, of course, the island is actually an atoll and the inner region is more of the sea. )